# Unable to get query to achieve specific result

Tags: database, kql, azure-log-analytics

I am working with azure logs and want to get better data for my monitoring. Since I never really worked with sql, kql and other I'm fairly new to it. Basic stuff is alright but currently I need/want to do something I have no idea how to achieve or if its even possible. I will post example data as well down bellow.

I have logs with columns: timestamp, message, operation_Name and operation_Id. With operation_Id I'm able to divide and group logs together. Than using message and timestamp I would like to get (in best case scenario) something like this:

logs example:

| timestamp | message | operation_Name | operation_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-31T14:32:31.709377Z | Executed Function X... | functionX | e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9 |
| 2023-01-31T14:32:31.7091679Z | Random log message... | functionX | e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9 |
| 2023-01-31T14:32:31.3316605Z | Request Part_Two of Function X ... | functionX | e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9 |
| 2023-01-31T14:32:30.8697249Z | Request Part_One of Function X ... | functionX | e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9 |
| 2023-01-31T14:32:29.3168458Z | Executing Function X... | functionX | e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9 |

result example:

| operation_Name | whole_time | special_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FunctionX | 0:0:1.3168458Z | 0:0:0.7168458Z |
| FunctionY | 0:0:2.3168458Z | 0:0:0.5268458Z |

Where **whole_time** is average time of all FunctionsX from 1st log to last and **special_time** is average time of all FunctionsX from log with specific message(*Request Part_One of Function X*) to log with specific message(*Request Part_Two of Function X*).

Option where it would be 2 queries( one for whole_time and one for special_time) is still great.

I tried to prepare example data (since it is from azure logs there are more columns but I believe for what I need they are irrelevant, but if not I can edit them in).

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, message:string, operation_Name:string, operation_Id:string)
[
    "2023-01-31T14:32:31.709377Z"  ,"Executed Function X..."             ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:31.7091679Z" ,"Random log message..."              ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:31.3316605Z" ,"Request Part_Two of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:30.8697249Z" ,"Request Part_One of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:29.3168458Z" ,"Executing Function X..."            ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:32.709377Z"  ,"Executed Function Y..."             ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:31.7091679Z" ,"Random log message..."              ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:31.3316605Z" ,"Request Part_Two of Function Y ..." ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:30.5697249Z" ,"Request Part_One of Function Y ..." ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:29.2168458Z" ,"Executing Function Y..."            ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:31.709377Z"  ,"Executed Function X..."             ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:31.7091679Z" ,"Random log message..."              ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:31.3316605Z" ,"Request Part_Two of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:30.8697249Z" ,"Request Part_One of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:29.6168458Z" ,"Executing Function X..."            ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
]
```

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7XUW2vCMBQH8PeB3yH0aYNakpPm1vcN9rKN4YM6hqS5iGBbp5Xt4y9VBzLnBdulT0lpfk3On2N1HZ587m7rWeFWtS4WmdW1a2YxCisrPXXZql7OymmMqoVb6npWlZMnXfy1/Gh3i3e9m7feDQojAgy0j0mfkgFJMwoZJYnAigoxjhCKo/svZ9a1s%20hhXZpmFzRMkiRC%20yOO/O7lMAoTh0EJEMY641LhJXXArbe5F1oR6lS0oeNjNOFCjZt9XnVpqwLNq%20nPUQ/kLmlKCeeYbWn3sQ73jV70sp4MPitU%20b0LQJv/6IzGieTh01Qd0s%20l%2008aVBIOLVMmN/S21iEfJ4rdAQ2bU8OZmI1OxGzU0BRAaiOtpZJboCw1uRYkJyC4z6lmx%20k2MWtNXxyz0e9at6Rxwi6NWcd0iBmcjtlBsTugSZZ20c0AK68gZQ6UpIRRZbxmRnEvDVUOmzN0m27Whm7Zza6nW3ezq%20kQM96um11Av38Dt3qZI5QHAAA=)

I will appreciate any help since I'm clueless how to achieve something like this or if it is even possible to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(timestamp:datetime, message:string, operation_Name:string, operation_Id:string)
[
    "2023-01-31T14:32:31.709377Z"  ,"Executed Function X..."             ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:31.7091679Z" ,"Random log message..."              ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:31.3316605Z" ,"Request Part_Two of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:30.8697249Z" ,"Request Part_One of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T14:32:29.3168458Z" ,"Executing Function X..."            ,"functionX" ,"e029727cdece47f83e26dfdbf7a913e9"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:32.709377Z"  ,"Executed Function Y..."             ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:31.7091679Z" ,"Random log message..."              ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:31.3316605Z" ,"Request Part_Two of Function Y ..." ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:30.5697249Z" ,"Request Part_One of Function Y ..." ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T12:32:29.2168458Z" ,"Executing Function Y..."            ,"functionY" ,"3228ac8dd386d2354cba71b1276fb3a5"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:31.709377Z"  ,"Executed Function X..."             ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:31.7091679Z" ,"Random log message..."              ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:31.3316605Z" ,"Request Part_Two of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:30.8697249Z" ,"Request Part_One of Function X ..." ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
   ,"2023-01-31T11:42:29.6168458Z" ,"Executing Function X..."            ,"functionX" ,"209f9245e29831539cfa5c96f8c39e0c"
]
| summarize whole_time   = max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) 
           ,special_time = take_anyif(timestamp, message startswith_cs "Request Part_Two") - take_anyif(timestamp, message startswith_cs "Request Part_One")
            by operation_Id, operation_Name
| summarize whole_time = avg(whole_time), special_time = avg(special_time) by operation_Name
```

| operation_Name | whole_time | special_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| functionX | 00:00:02.2425312 | 00:00:00.4619356 |
| functionY | 00:00:03.4925312 | 00:00:00.7619356 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA7WWTW/bMAyG7/4VhE814BiW5C8ZyLEDdtmGoYemxWDI%20kiNxXZmK0s77MdPTrrFTZa0iFLpJArkI4ovKAmmzSwX8kpXtew1q5e5YFoOKx%20MpWdzmfe6q5q5D%201SdkxXbVN8YvX/zB/Fs9Fz7h0ww8UhJpMQTQi6QVFOcE5QkIaUpOmdC%20C714%20Sr7QU8GHV8CEG3AZB4MJ4%20K563rx1zUKGmKY45UJyGaUqIxInQolSpYwiIqnrbHyOkFGS0rshzFfWiLaGRTv/m%20cB%20IJkQlCShPGWLH%20szF3DF9bp4mbdQqtG6cPmGJcih0GWGM%20IHpI/N/IdyZgGJuUsirMNeVtno4wThbYn403O%20BWFzU4obDaQCcYZ45kQJEsEJnHES5aiEuE0USVh8VGyjcJsyW9W2Gy/znbkMIjfqrDLko3C8GmFHRTanozy6BI9DIdUURzFEtOMoJhQrljMaaIyTqgM%20WmyTQ%20zIFv2sLPJ1j3sXLJRWGLXw14nf3N%20Q7%20qa9ZVvySsH9qFLIbX18SaQs0edw%20zBxOoq2ZscMbkfil5xRZb7ylo9l0WrHmq1M7j35MOZtnpfl3ph4L3cFBOd4CdH8GUxfXGh4Py6cU3Yf8vcewSpsB%20zq92Bs%20HvTSH/bHJe4kagv8B%20%20rOH%20UIAAA=)